# Java 8 generic type check

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

In Java 7 different types for the checked method causes compile error, while in Java 8 there is no compile error. Is it possible to keep the generics in checked and make it create compile error in Java 8?

```
class CheckedEquals{
    public static <T> boolean checked(T expected, T actual) {
       return com.google.common.base.Objects.equal(expected, actual);
    }
}

class ShouldFailAtCompileTime{
    public void foo(){
        if(CheckedEquals.checked("String", Boolean.TRUE)){
            System.err.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your example, T is Object... Not sure why it doesn't compile with Java 7.

Comment: @assylias Right but it is kind of the core point of the question. :)

Comment: Can you include the compile error in the question?

Comment: It looks like the IDE was smart. The compiler never reported an error. Idea in some cases throws an error, but later versions of Eclipse does not report any problems.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour **not** to cause a compile error is correct here, since the generic type parameter `T` is `Object`. How else should the compiler guess the type parameter if it isn't specified? I wonder how Java 7 did that, as far as I know there were no changes.

This one would lead to a compile error however:

```
CheckedEquals.<String>checked("String", Boolean.TRUE)
```

Comment: The compiler can actually guess type parameters that are not specified.  In fact it is not guessing it's type inference.  See the [type inference article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) in the Oracle java tutorials.  From what I can remeber type inference has been improved in Java 8 (see also https://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/25/a-lesser-known-java-8-feature-generalized-target-type-inference/).  My guess is that Java 7 cannot infer a type for `T` but Java 8, with the improved inference, can.  In this case Java 8 infers `Object` for `T`.

Comment: I think that Java 7 guesses that the expected and actual must have the same type.